# NSUserDefaults is not saving globally

Tags: xcode, swift, nsuserdefaults

I have a NSUser Bool() that is in the a global. when i close the app and run it again the bool does save but when i take my exit sugue to my sKcene the sKcene still thinks the Bool value is what it originally was even if. I have change the value using the SwitchMainOnOff function. please help.

```
import AVFoundation
import Foundation
import SpriteKit
import GameKit
import UIKit
import iAd



var buttonState = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("buttonState") as! Bool

class SoundController: UIViewController {

func SwitchMainOnOff() {

        if SwitchMain.on == true {
            println("SwitchMain is on from function")
            SwitchMain.on = true
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(Bool(true), forKey:"buttonState")



        }
        if SwitchMain.on == false {
            println("SwitchMain is off from function")
            SwitchMain.on = false
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(Bool(false), forKey:"buttonState")

        }


     }
func Correct() {
    if buttonState == true{
        println("SwitchMain is on")
        SwitchMain.on = true
    }

    if buttonState == false{
        println("SwitchMain is off ")
        SwitchMain.on = false
    }
  }

@IBAction func SwitchMain(sender: AnyObject) {
    SwitchMainOnOff()


    }
```

I have a UISwitch that will change as shown to check if the Bool saved when moving to other scenes. It called SwitchMain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set your bool in NSUserDefaults this way:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "buttonState")
```

And your code will be:

```
if SwitchMain.on == true {
    println("SwitchMain is on from function")
    SwitchMain.on = true
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "buttonState")

}
    if SwitchMain.on == false {
    println("SwitchMain is off from function")
    SwitchMain.on = false
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(false, forKey: "buttonState")

}
```

And read values this way:

```
let switchState = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("buttonState")
```

Answer (score 0):

Please call following method after you update `NSUserDefaults`:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

Also, mould the code as Dharmesh has mentioned below.